# How to connect QSslSocket::error signal to slot using new QObject::connect syntax with function pointers?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to compile this code.

Header:

```
#ifndef SOCKETTEST_H
#define SOCKETTEST_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QSslSocket>

class SocketTest : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit SocketTest(QObject *parent = 0);

signals:

public slots:
    void onError(QAbstractSocket::SocketError socketError);

};

#endif // SOCKETTEST_H
```

Source:

```
#include "sockettest.h"

SocketTest::SocketTest(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
    QSslSocket *socket = new QSslSocket(this);
    connect(socket, &QSslSocket::error, this, &SocketTest::onError);
}
```

But I'm getting this error :

sockettest.cpp:7: error: no matching function for call to 'SocketTest::connect(QSslSocket*&, , SocketTest* const, void (SocketTest::*)(QAbstractSocket::SocketError))'

I want to use new syntax of connect() function:

```
QMetaObject::Connection QObject::connect(const QObject * sender, PointerToMemberFunction signal, const QObject * receiver, PointerToMemberFunction method, Qt::ConnectionType type = Qt::AutoConnection) [static]
```

So, my question is: How to connect `QSslSocket::error()` signal to `SocketTest::onError()` slot using new syntax of connect function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem: there is another `error()` in this class. See [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qsslsocket-members.html), so you should use special trick:

```
  QObject::connect(socket, static_cast<void (QSslSocket::*)(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)>(&QAbstractSocket::error), [socket] (QAbstractSocket::SocketError) {
        qDebug()<< "ERROR " << socket->errorString();
        socket->deleteLater();
    });
}
```

Compilable example:

```
QSslSocket *socket = new QSslSocket(this);
connect(socket, static_cast<void (QSslSocket::*)(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)>(&QAbstractSocket::error), [socket] (QAbstractSocket::SocketError) {
    qDebug()<< "ERROR " << socket->errorString();
    socket->deleteLater();
});
socket->connectToHostEncrypted("imap.example.com", 993);
```

I know that this code very ugly but it is only one way to achieve what you want, or of course you can use old syntax.

As [doc](http://qt-project.org/wiki/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax#9f476f2409f0f1c353cdc621d8e4dd42) said:

> Overload
>
> As you might see in the example, connecting to QAbstractSocket::error
>   is not really beautiful since error has an overload, and taking the
>   address of an overloaded function requires explicit casting.
>
> Some macro could help (with c++11 or typeof extensions)
>
> The best thing is probably to recommend not to overload signals or
>   slots …
>
> … but we have been adding overloads in past minor releases of Qt
>   because taking the address of a function was not a use case we
>   support. But now this would be impossible without breaking the source
>   compatibility.