# How to connect to QTcpSocket error signal in Qt

Tags: qt, qtcpsocket

I am trying to get the QTcpSocket error by using signal and slot. I did like this:

```
connect(clientConnection->tcpSocket, &QTcpSocket::error, this, &ClientInterface::displayError);

void ClientInterface::displayError()
{
    qDebug() << clientConnection->tcpSocket->error();
    qDebug() << clientConnection->tcpSocket->errorString();
}
```

but I got this error:

> error: no matching function for call to 'ClientInterface::connect(QTcpSocket*&, , ClientInterface*, void (ClientInterface::*)())'
>        connect(clientConnection->tcpSocket, &QTcpSocket::error, this, &ClientInterface::displayError);

I also tried to implement the slot with `QAbstractSocket::SocketError` parameter like this:
 `void displayError(QAbstractSocket::SocketError);`
But it showed the same error.

Where did I do wrong?

**Edit:**
I tried to connect like this as the answer says:

```
connect(clientConnection->tcpSocket, QOverload<QAbstractSocket::SocketError>::of(&QAbstractSocket::error), this, &ClientInterface::displayError);
```

But I got this problem:

> QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'QAbstractSocket::SocketError'
>   (Make sure 'QAbstractSocket::SocketError' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27378658/how-to-connect-qsslsocketerror-signal-to-slot-using-new-qobjectconnect-synta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to overload the QAbstractSocket error:

```
connect(tcpSocket, QOverload<QAbstractSocket::SocketError>::of(&QAbstractSocket::error),

            this, &ClientInterface::displayError);
```

Comment: I tried your way to overload the QAbstractSocket error, but somehow it just showed me another error messages : QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'QAbstractSocket::SocketError'
(Make sure 'QAbstractSocket::SocketError' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)

Comment: Have you declared your displayError like this: `displayError(QAbstractSocket::SocketError socketError)`

Comment: Also try to `#include <QAbstractSocket>`

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, you will need some overload magic and register QAbstractSocket::SocketError as metatype.

This is also descriped in the Qt docs:

Qt 5:
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html#error

Qt 4.8
http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qabstractsocket.html#error

You may also use the SIGNAL(...) macro instead of the function pointer syntax to overcome this problem:

Example:

```
QObject::connect(clientConnection->tcpSocket, SIGNAL(error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)),
this, SLOT(displayError(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)));
```